# Multiple file upload at the same time in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
form.html
{% for fields in form %}
   <div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="{{ field.id_for_label }}"> 
   {{fields.label}}</label>
   <div class="controls">
   {{fields}}
   {% if fields.label == 'Photo' %}
    <br>
    <p></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary success" 
    id="add_new_file">+ Add Another File</button>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  </div>
<script>
    $("#add_new_file").click(function(){
        $("p").append('<input type="file"><br>');
    });
</script>
```

[image]

For every click in + Add Another File button, another input file option added. Here i use model form to insert into the database.The first one is adder into the db, but how can i add multiple photo or other types files at the same time.

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_values = Registration_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)

    multiple_files = request.POST
    print(multiple_files)
    for file in multiple_files:
        print(file)

    if form_values.is_valid():
        data = form_values.save(commit=False)



        password = data.password.encode('utf-8')
        password = hashlib.sha256(password).hexdigest()
        data.password = password

        activation_code = str(random.randrange(0, 999999))
        data.activation_code = activation_code

        data.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need to save the files blindly to storage ( project directory) and there are no model relationships.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for data in request.FILES.values():
            with open(data.name, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(data.read())
        # do other stuff
```

This will write/create new files to your project directory from `request.FILES

Comment: What you mean ?

Comment: i edit the line as  $("p").append('{{form.photo}}<br>'); Now it is related to model? If then how can i get all the file in view.py

Comment: for file in request.FILES:
            print(request.FILES[file]) is giving me just the last selected file name